# Change underscore.js codes to php

Tags: php, underscore.js

would you tell me, how can I rewrite this line in php ? I do not understand it.

```
var last = .map(.filter(brackets, function(b) { 
    return b.nextGame == i; 
}), function(b) { 
    return { 
        game: b.bracketNo,
        teams: b.teamnames
    }; 
});
```

it is on underscore.js;

Comment: Please provide some more context, where does this piece of code comes from exactly and what do you want to reach with it. Moreover, this is not valid JavaScript, so I am curious which language it is instead.

Comment: @JeroenNoten it's on this link [Tournament Bracket Generator](https://gist.github.com/sterlingwes/4199115)

Comment: and i want to sort the brackets array (actually struc which using in renderBrackets function) like what getBracket do BUT in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is (something like) this:

```
$last = array_map(function($b) {
    return [
        'game' => $b['bracketNo'],
        'teams' => $b['teamnames']
    ];
}, array_filter($brackets, function($b) {
    return $b['nextGame'] == $i; 
}));
```

Or, if you are using objects instead of associative arrays:

```
$last = array_map(function($b) {
    return (object) [
        'game' => $b->bracketNo,
        'teams' => $b->teamnames
    ];
}, array_filter($brackets, function($b) {
    return $b->nextGame == $i; 
}));
```

Note that the order of parameters in PHP's array_map is different from UnderscoreJS' map function.